# Database design under Django

Tags: django, database-design

I have a probably quite basic question: I am currently setting up a database for students and their marks in my courses. I currently have two main classes in my models.py: Student (containing their name, id, email address etc) and Course (containing an id, the year it is running in and the assessment information - for example "Essay" "40%" "Presentation" "10%" "Exam" "50%"). And, of course, Student has a ManyToMany field so that I can assign students to courses and vice versa. I have to be able to add and modify these things.

Now, obviously, I would like to be able to add the marks for the students in the different assignments (which are different from course to course). As I am very unexperienced in database programming, I was hoping one of you could give me a tip how to set this up within my models.

Thanks,
Tobi

Comment: show us ur models. what have you tried so far and what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the way to go about it is to have a separate class for assignment, something like this.

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    ASSIGNMENT_TYPES = (
        ('essay', "Essay"),
        ...
    )
    ASSIGNMENT_GRADES = (
        ('a+', "A+"),
        ('a', "A"),
        ...
    )
    student = models.ForeignKey("Student")
    course = models.ForeignKey("Course")
    assignment_type = models.CharField(choices=ASSIGNMENT_TYPES, max_length=15, default='essay')
    progress = models.IntegerField()
    grade = models.CharField(choices=ASSIGNMENT_GRADES, max_length=3, default="a+")
```

This way you have one assignment connected to one student and one course. It can be modified relatively easy if you have multiple students per one assignment, by adding another class (for example StudentGroup) and including it in the model.

Hope that this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a model called "Assessments", which has a foreign key to Course. In addition ,create a field called "Assessment Type", another called "Assessment Result" and a final one called "Assesment Date". Should look like this:

```
ASSESSMENTS = (('E','Essay'),('P','Presentation'))

class Assessment(models.MOdel):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course')
    assessment = models.CharField(choices=ASESSMENTS)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    taken_on = models.DateField()
    overall_result = models.BooleanField()
    is_complete = models.BooleanField()
```

Each time there is an exam, you fill in a record in this table for each assessment taken. You can use the overall result as a flag to see if the student has passed or failed, and the is_complete to see if there are any exams pending for a course.

Comment: How do I add the Student taking the Assessment though? With another ForeignKey?

Comment: Yep, exactly. So now you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `models.py` file of [classcomm](http://code.google.com/p/classcomm/source/browse/django_projects/classcomm/student_portal/models.py), 
a content management system written in Django for delivering and managing Courses on the Web.

It has following Models

1. Department
2. Course
3. Instructor
4. Mentor
5. Enrollment
6. Assignment
7. DueDateOverride
8. Submission
9. Grade
10. ExtraCredit
11. Information
12. Resource
13. Announcement

You may not need such a complex relationship for you case, but it's wort looking into it's `models design`.

You can find more details on [homepage](http://code.google.com/p/classcomm/) of this project.